# Python time comparison format issues with time.strptime function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to verify the cert expiring in 5 days using the time & datetime lib :

```
   print("Got date is >>>>", got_date)
        expiry_date = time.strptime(got_date["Enddate"], "%Y/%m/%d %H")
        print(" Expiry date is >>>>", expiry_date)
        today = datetime.now()
        print(" Today date is >>>", today)
        days_left = today - expiry_date
        print(days_left)
        if days_left > 5:
            print("Cert is expiring", i)
        else:
            print("Cert is not expiring for",i)
```

but then i'm getting a error :

```
*('Got date is >>>>', {'00': '00', 'Enddate': '2019/01/29 00'})*
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/license_check.py", line 44, 
in <module>
    days_left = today - expiry_date
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 
'time.struct_time'*
**(' Expiry date is >>>>', time.struct_time(tm_year=2019, tm_mon=1, 
tm_mday=29, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=29, 
tm_isdst=-1))**
**(' Today date is >>>', datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 29, 18, 55, 8, 225000))**
```

i know that i'm trying to compare 2 different formats here but i'm not really sure on how do get both of expiry & today dates to same format so i can know if the cert is actually getting expired in 5 days.
Also , i'm not able to convert the variable today same as expiry_date using time.strptime function.

Very new to Python using version 2.7, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `datetime.datetime.strptime`

**Ex:**

```
Enddate = '2019/01/29 00'
expiry_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(Enddate, "%Y/%m/%d %H")
today = datetime.datetime.now()

days_left = today - expiry_date
print(days_left)
```